# Why can't I see new Controller in Swagger UI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, swagger-ui

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API. I have 5 existing controllers. However, when I added a 6th controller, the same exact way, and added one route, when I run my Swagger it doesn't show.

Locally, and when I deployed to Dev (Azure App Svc).

However true I am able to add a new method/route to existing controllers and they do show up in Swagger.

I've restarted VS, restarted machine... I've deleted the `bin` and `obj` folders from every project in the solution.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

-------------------- Updates -----------------------

1. Looked today, noticed an "exclimation" icon over the **Packages**

[image]

2. Not that my explaintion is any different than this, but for those who don't know code, or can't get the proper visual at the proper time, here you go... (not that it says anymore than what I have already said)...haha

"A-B-C...X-Y-Z, now I know my ABC's"... (listen kids) @Dai @Ibram

@Oliver, what kind of question is that "is the controller in the same... huh" --- MAJOR NARF moment... haha

As you see, here are all the controllers in the project:
[image]

However, 2 aren't rendering in Swagger

[image]

Conversely, I am able to extend the exising controllers by adding new routes and all works as expected. However these two, or any others I add since last night don't show up in swagger, but funny I actually hit the route via Postman:

[image]

[image]

Even wilder, when I send this payload to the API it says "ConnectionString" has no value!

[image]

Finally I re-state as I said w/o having to loose more time to add this supplemental images:

```
I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API. I have 5 existing controllers. However, when I added a 6th controller, the same exact way, and added one route, when I run my Swagger it doesn't show.

Locally, and when I deployed to Dev (Azure App Svc).

However true I am able to add a new method/route to existing controllers and they do show up in Swagger.

I've restarted VS, restarted machine... I've deleted the bin and obj folders from every project in the solution.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.
```

Comment: We can't help you without seeing your code.

Comment: Swagger uses Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer, so if asp.net finds your controller, then by default Swagger should found it too and display it, Unless you explicitly ignore it!!

Comment: Include in the question, How we can reproduce the same problem ?

Comment: Is your controller in the same project as your API server? Otherwise add a reference of the controller project to the API project.

Comment: Check your bin folder and take a look into your assembly by using ILSpy and check if it contains your controller.

Comment: Hi,@Robert Green MBA,please share a minimal example that could reproduce the issue

Comment: @ All yall! Worst case I will just create a new API and copy/paste; but I wanted to reach out to the community to see if there was some larger issue at hand, and see if there was something totally incorrect I did. I have been doing this for 20 years and this never happened.

Comment: @Dai  I added images and re-stated what I already said; guess you guys have never encountered this issue.

Comment: @IbramReda I added images and re-stated what I already said; guess you guys have never encountered this issue.

Comment: @Oliver I added images and re-stated what I already said; guess you guys have never encountered this issue.

Comment: @RobertGreenMBA The problem looks like you're referencing an **old** (non-ASP.NET Core) NuGet package. You can't use NuGet packages for older ASP.NET versions in an ASP.NET Core project.

Comment: @RobertGreenMBA Make sure that your new controllers are **.net 6** controllers, which mean it inherit from `ControllerBase`  Class NOT from `ApiController` and does not use `System.Web.Http` namespace!

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a controller called `UtilityController` or `ValuesController` they won't render. But I created a new one called `XUtilityController` and it worked. Hope this helps someone else out.